# How to create a sliding navigation bar like in apple's website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

When viewing apple's website on my iPhone, it has very cool transparent navigation menu bar. I wonder how it is done. 
[website link](http://www.apple.com/ca/iphone/)

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not really a question.

Comment: Sorry Stella, that is not how StackOverflow is designed to work. Questions should be more specific... along the lines of "I tried this, it's not working, I get this error, when I expect this result". Not "This is cool, how do I do it?"

Comment: @JonP ok,now I'll know for the next time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the code that is responsible for how a web site looks:

1. Download, install and open Google Chrome
2. Visit the website that you want to inspect
3. Right click the element that you want to inspect
4. View the elements html markup and css styling.

You can recreate a navigation bar like apples in html:

```
<nav>
    <div class="navicon">
      &#9776;
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="yourimagesource.com/image.jpg" />
    </div>
</nav
```

Use the following css to give the navbar a transparent background like Apple:

```
nav {
  height: 2.55556em;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  font-size: 18px;
}

.navicon {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding:0 0.25em;
}
```

The key point is that for transparency like this you can use an rgba color (with an 'a' value less than one) to create a transparent background background.

You could also declare `opacity:0.6;` however, this will probably produce some unwanted side effects (images / links within the nav will have an opacity of 0.6 as well).

Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/8orhey7g/)

Comment: Thanks. I'm am actually more interested in how the list in the menu has a sliding effect.

Comment: updated answer w info on how you can explore the code behind this type of thing.